# Find and replace data from columns - Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

So I'm a complete noobie at anything slightly more complex spreadsheet wise but here's the issue. I'm looking to replace data in a range of cells (A) that matches data from a reference column (Y), with new data from the adjacent column with corresponding data (Z).

Essentially a clever formula I could use to edit a csv containing an email column (A). My thinking was this: I add 2 new columns (Y & Z for example)from a separate sheet, here I have in column Y - all relevant emails that are to be updated (also contained in column A). In column Z - all new emails to be updated to. Both Y & Z have data in corresponding rows(Y3 - Z3 = current - new email). Assuming current emails are found in column A, I guess something like:

-if data in column Y matches data in cell of Column A,
-replace with data from corresponding cell in column Z.

...and runs recursively to go through all of column Y.

Apologies for the lengthy explanation and if this is already an obvious solution which I haven't found!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12OsYiBOD_WjfP3E6AdUQb4ITLtyoL7UreEaZfbaXQ9I/edit?usp=sharing thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
={"NEW"; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C, I:J, 2, 0)))}
```

[image]